# Crealtity Ender 3 extruder

Tags: creality-ender-3

I had a very similar experience as another member. I have Ender 3 with BLTouch which had been working amazing until a while ago. It was running a print overnight and when I got up in the morning the print had failed and the BLTouch had completely broken off.

Since then, we had our friend print a new hinge for it and we've managed to get it kinda working until recently. All one a sudden it prints about an inch and then just stops pushing filament through it also seems to stretch it.

I'm a newbie and am not all up on the lingo but I do know a bit. Apologies, I'm very new to this and also sight impaired. So whatever I try to print will stop actually printing when the item gets to around an inch in height although the printer continues behaving as though it's still printing but no more filament comes through the nozzle. I hope this is making some sense. I will try and get another print going but today we can't even get filament going through at all.

Comment: You mention the extruder in your title then in the body of your post the BLTouch. Could you please [edit] clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: This sounds as if there is a problem with the extruder, please check if the extruder lever is broken. Another reason can be heat creep since it happens after a while. Please update by [edit] to include printing parameters like temperatures, cooling and speeds.

Comment: I would agree with Oscar.  Chep at Filament Friday posted a video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXe7bftyMFU .  I would also check the nozzle.  A partial clog can cause similar issues.